# Conditional render React Native

Tags: react-native

why conditional `render()` in React Native is called many times ?
My code is like this:

```
render(){
    if (this.state.type === 'admin')
        return(<Image />);
    else 
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this :

```
render(){

return(

{this.state.type === 'admin'?<Image />:null}
)

}
```

hope its clear. feel free for doubts